# Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

Tags: flutter

Tengo problemas al ingresar una dependencia. La idea es poder visualizar un archivo PDF desde una URL. Según he visto en la WEB se realiza agregando una de las dependencias para PDF, detallo las dependencias que he intentado utilizar y me aparece el mismo error:

- flutter_full_pdf_viewer
- pdf_viewer_plugin
- flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer
- flutter_pdfview

Cada ves que intento agregar alguna de las dependencias, me sale el siguiente error:

```
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\75.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\80.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\85.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\90.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\95.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\100.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\105.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\110.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\115.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\120.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\125.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\130.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\135.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\140.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\145.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\150.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\155.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\160.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\165.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\170.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\175.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\180.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\185.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\190.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\191.jar, 
C:\Users\Ladislao\AndroidStudioProjects\lukinapp\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\192.jar
              Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
              Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

            * Try:
            Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

            * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

            BUILD FAILED in 2s
            *******************************************************************************************
            The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX 

incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
            *******************************************************************************************
            Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Si alguien sabe por que me dice que esta dependencia esta duplicada. Este es mi archivo pubspec.yaml

```
    # The following defines the version and build number for your application.
    # A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
    # followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
    # Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
    # build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
    # In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
    # Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
    # In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
    # Read more about iOS versioning at
    # https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
    version: 1.0.0+1

    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter

      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21+11
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
      flutter_signin_button: ^1.0.0
      font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
      flutter_screenutil: ^0.6.1
      http: 0.12.0+2
      flutter_pdfview: ^1.0.0+9

    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter

    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:

      # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
      # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
      # the material Icons class.
      uses-material-design: true

      # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
      # assets:
      #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
      #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
      assets:
        - assets/

      # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

      # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

      # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
      # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
      # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
      # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
      # example:
      # fonts:
      #   - family: Schyler
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
      #         style: italic
      #   - family: Trajan Pro
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
      #         weight: 700
      #
      # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
      # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este problema se puede presentar por diversas razones:

1. Incompatibilidad en tu SdkVersion, por ende te recomienda asegurarte que la minSdkVersion para tu proyecto es 20 o superior. Mínima para flutter_pdfview es [20](https://github.com/endigo/flutter_pdfview/issues/11#issuecomment-498456114).

`android > app > buil.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 20 // minSdkVersion
    }
```

2. Migrar a AndroidX([como migrar](https://flutter-es.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility)) puede evitar conflictos entre los pluging o errores Gradle. Para saber si tu proyecto esta usando AndroidX asegúrate de que `android/gradle.properties` contenga:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Por ultimo, corre `flutter clean` y compila tu proyecto.

Comment: No me funciono :( y ademas se agregaron estas lineas antes del error que puse. >Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: Indagando un poco mas veo que también una incompatibilidad relacionada con AndroidX puede causar el error, por ende modifique mi respuesta, espero y te funcione.

Comment: Gracias!! ahi funko,